# Go channel buffer length - best practice

Tags: go, channel

I'm currently learning Go and have started to re-write a test-data-generation program I originally wrote in Java. I've been intrigued by Go's channels / threading possibilities, as many of the programs I've written have been focused around load testing a system / recording various metrics.

Here, I am creating some data to be written out to a CSV file. I started out by generating all of the data, then passing that off to be written to a file. I then thought I'd try and implement a channel, so data could be written while it's still being generated.

It worked - it almost eliminated the overhead of generating the data first and *then* writing it. However, I found that this only worked if I had a channel with a buffer big enough to cope with all of the test data being generated: `c := make(chan string, count)`, where count is the same size as the number of test data lines I am generating.

So, to my question: I'm regularly generating millions of records of test data (load test applications) - should I be using a channel with a buffer that large? I can't find much about restrictions on the size of the buffer?

Running the below with a 10m count completes in ~59.5s; generating the data up front and writing it all to a file takes ~62s; using a buffer length of 1 - 100 takes ~80s.

```
const externalRefPrefix = "Ref"
const fileName = "citizens.csv"

var counter int32 = 0

func WriteCitizensForApplication(applicationId string, count int) {
    file, err := os.Create(fileName)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer file.Close()

    c := make(chan string, count)

    go generateCitizens(applicationId, count, c)

    for line := range c {
        file.WriteString(line)
    }
}

func generateCitizens(applicationId string, count int, c chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        c <- fmt.Sprintf("%v%v\n", applicationId, generateExternalRef())
    }
    close(c)
}

func generateExternalRef() string {
    atomic.AddInt32(&COUNTER, 1)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v%08d", externalRefPrefix, counter)
}
```

Comment: You're problem is IO bound, the goroutine is only adding extra overhead. Start by using buffered IO to improve performance. (also, reading the counter value directly defeats the purpose of using atomics)

Comment: There aren't any hard restrictions on buffer size.  A buffered channel has functionally the same memory footprint as an array of that type.  In this case, it's a channel of strings, which are each two machine words long.  Thus the memory footprint of your channel buffer will be 16 (or 8, on 32-bit systems) bytes multiplied by the buffer size.  A million-sized buffer is still only ~16 MB.

Comment: Thank you both, some good info there! On the atomic - it's not being used properly here I know (still playing with the structure etc), but thanks for the pointer on reading directly, will probably save me some headaches down the line!

Comment: Also note that once your data generation is fast enough to outpace the writer (i.e., once IO is your bottleneck), continuing to buffer does nothing but increase memory usage. It won't get any faster than it can write to disk. Your data generation might as well just wait until more has been written to disk unless there is some particular reason not to.

Comment: Yeah I realise the bottleneck is IO - but it was still a bit quicker to throw the data as it was generated onto the channel.
@JimB the bufferedIO writer has slashed my write time down to ~6s! It doesn't seem to benefit from a buffer size of more than 50 or so...